# Twenty Eleven Theme

Tags: categories, pages

I have edited the pages and categories to all look the same and have a right sidebar, so when I click to a page or category they are same layout and also search results and archives and tag archives.

However when I click on the post title or posted on date the layout is different (no sidebar).

Does anyone know how I can make this look the same as other pages/categories with the right sidebar or which file I need to edit in the directory?

Comment: Turn on debugging to see what template page you are loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

to `single.php` in the same place as the other files, i.e. right before

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

You also need to go to style.css, and remove the margins for .singular and .singular #content, .left-sidebar.singular #content.

In version 1.5 of this theme css only has,

```
.singular #content,
.left-sidebar.singular #content
```

Plus you need to take the margin: and width: set for #primary{} ID and copy/paste to .singular #primary{}

Comment: Why do you think that this helps?

Comment: @kaiser See edit. I tested it on mine, and it works.

Comment: IMO he just doesn't know what template he got... *Edit* Just read your edit. Ok might fit now :)